# PyQt: QCheckBox text on the left?

Tags: python, text, pyqt, qcheckbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change checkbox position for a QCheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189951/change-checkbox-position-for-a-qcheckbox)

This is a really straight-forward question: how can I make the QCheckBox text to be on the left side of the checkbox and not on the right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189951/change-checkbox-position-for-a-qcheckbox

Comment: Even easier...

Use the QWidget.setLayoutDirection method and set it RightToLeft vs. LeftToRight

You can do this in Designer or through code, it is a property or all widgets.